# Gstreamer stream audio over network

Tags: gstreamer, audio-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to get real-time audio streaming working from my mac to my windows PC, using Gstreamer but i havent had any luck.

This is what i am using on my mac to send the audio:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v osxaudiosrc ! tcpserversink port=7777 host=0.0.0.0
```

And then on the windows side trying to recieve with

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe tcpclientsrc port=7777 host=mac.local ! autoaudiosink
```

I have browsed the other answers on here but none of them helped or are outdated

I have tried this with ffmpeg but that has a snatchy sound in it, so trying gstreaming hoping it will better